# Fuzzy matching latitude and longitude with (somewhat) Big Data

Tags: r

I've got 75,000 coordinates that are analogous to the following example data:

```
addresses <- structure(list(address_lat = c(-175.33, -175.20, -177.65, -174.10, -175.80, 
-179.50, -179.23, -179.12, -178.75, -174.77), address_lon = c(70.25, 
69.75, 62.23, 60.50, 66.25, 61.75, 62.54, 63.70, 61.45, -15.80)), .Names = c("address_lat", "address_lon"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

and I need to do fuzzy matching on the GeoNames data ([from here](http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/), e.g. "US.zip").

This gives me about 500,000 rows of data. I want to match my coordinates against those in the GeoNames data, which as far as I know means using a distance matrix, returning the closest rows of data from the "US" file for each of my 75,000 lat/lon pairs.

I have to do this offline because there are too many rows to run it against a web service.

Theoretically, I know how to do this:

```
unzip("US.zip")
require(data.table)
US <- as.data.frame(fread("US.txt")) # data.table or data.frame, either way
library(geosphere)
D = distm(US[, c(6,5)], addresses)
geo <- cbind(addresses, US[apply(D, 1, which.min),])
```

The only problem is that it would take like a Terabyte of RAM or more to run this. So I get the

> cannot allocate vector of size XXXX

error.

Is there a practical way to do this? I tried chunking it but even a few hundred rows at a time is too much.

Comment: @Arun I'm just matching latitude and longitude against the GeoNames geographical data. I have no domain expertise with geographic data either. I'm just getting geo/location data from this popular data source. http://www.geonames.org/  So basically given a lat/lon I mainly just want to know the city, so that I have better features for my statistical models.

Comment: okay, thanks. I'll try to understand the solution from Bryan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly, but see if this helps:

```
require(data.table)
US <- as.data.frame(fread("US.txt")) # data.table or data.frame, either way
US<-data.table(US[,c(2,6,5)]) ##just makes it easier for demonstration. 
colnames(US)<-c("city", "lat", "long")

setkey(US, lat, long)

fuzzyMatch<-function(data, fuzzSize = 10, n.results = 3){
  f<-fuzzSize
  cities<-list()
 for(i in 1:nrow(data)){
  myLat<-data[i,1]
  myLong<-data[i,2]

  temp<-US[ lat %between% c(myLat-f, myLat+f)][long %between% c(myLong-f, myLong+f)]
  cities[i]<-unique(temp[sample(nrow(temp), n.results, replace = T),1, with = F])
 }
  return(cities)
}
```

Variable `fuzzSize` will be the size of the grid square you use to search, and `n.results` is how many of the nearby cities it returns. I added this because sometimes it would return 500 and sometimes it returns 0. You may need to fine tune/adjust the output to meet your needs, but hopefully that helps.

EDIT: You could also remove the `n.results` and then just use the selected cities nearby to use the `dist` approach you tried before. The smaller subsets *should* be more memory-feasible.